# $q\in Q×Q → f(q)=3$, so then $∀x∈R² → f(x)=3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, topological-groups

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.
Also suppose that for every  $q \in \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ 
we have $f(q)=3$,
then show that: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have $f(x)=3$.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you, for instance, have done this proof if it was about a function $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ instead of a function $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$? The proof is _very_ similar.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to solve your problem:

1. Write down the definition for continuity of $f$ using quantifiers ($\forall,\,\exists$)
2. Substitute in the things you know into this, e.g how distances are measured in $\mathbb R^2$
3. Write down the one useful thing you know about the relationship between the reals and rationals (I.e. that for any real one can find an arbitrarily close rational)
4. Write it down with quantifiers
5. Write down what you want to prove
6. Stare really hard at it
7. Write down the proof